# Getting all expenses from Quickbooks Desktop

Tags: quickbooks

I'm able to read all expenses from QuickBooks Desktop with C# code using QuickBooks SDK. Once I have the expenses I need to copy them to Salesforce and when new expenses arrive those need to move to Salesforce as well.

So I'm able to connect to the app and get a collection of expenses. Here's the code.

```
//Connect to QuickBooks and begin a session
sessionManager.OpenConnection("", "test");
connectionOpen = true;
sessionManager.BeginSession(@"C:\TEST.qbw", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
sessionBegun = true;

ICreditCardChargeQuery creditQuery = requestMsgSet.AppendCreditCardChargeQueryRq();
creditQuery.IncludeLineItems.SetValue(true);
IMsgSetResponse msgSetRs = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
IResponse response = msgSetRs.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
ICreditCardChargeRetList checkRetList = (ICreditCardChargeRetList)response.Detail;
```

I have two questions.

1. Do I have to read CreditCard and Check separately or is there a way to get all expenses from one place?
2. Is there a way to get only latest data? Say I get all the expenese up to today. Tomorrow two more get added. Is there a way to get only the two that were added? I can do this by date of the expense but I'm asking if there a system way of handling this. Maybe mark it as received and only read received ones or is there a way to say give me expenses in a date range as opposed to the way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to read CreditCard and Check separately or is there a way to get all expenses from one place?

QuickBooks does support a `TransactionQuery` request type that you could use to get this data in a single request, *but* it only returns summary details -- it doesn't return details such as individual line items, etc.

Chances are, you'll probably have to reach them seperately if you want any sort of meaningful details.

You can refer to the OSR for reference:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

> Is there a way to get only latest data?

You can use the `ModifiedDateRangeFilter` filters to do this. e.g.:

```
//Set field value for FromModifiedDate
CheckQueryRq.ORTxnQuery.TxnFilter.ORDateRangeFilter.ModifiedDateRangeFilter.FromModifiedDate.SetValue(DateTime.Parse("12/15/2007 12:15:12"),false);

//Set field value for ToModifiedDate
CheckQueryRq.ORTxnQuery.TxnFilter.ORDateRangeFilter.ModifiedDateRangeFilter.ToModifiedDate.SetValue(DateTime.Parse("12/15/2007 12:15:12"),false);
```

You can refer to the QuickBooks OSR for full details.